# Pari GP most current version?

Tags: upgrade

I see at http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html the most current version of Pari/GP is pari-2.7.1.tar.gz , but I am looking for the Ubuntu distro with it or would like to know when the current one would have it? I currently am running Pari 2.5.5 from the current Ubuntu 14.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I was looking for:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/amd64/pari-gp/2.7.1-1

After installing this it seems to work.

Thanks Wild man, it help to know what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Software from third parties are only updated when a new release comes out, so if the newest version of the application was released and had time to be tested before ubuntu's freeze on adding new software it could have been included in 14.04.

To answer your question the soonest it will become available in the repositories will be at the next release of ubuntu if ubuntu still chooses to include it in the repositories, so if you must have the latest you will need to get it from the third party developer, but it is best that it is in an trusted ppa or .deb package.

If the application is in a ppa you can add it so it can be installed with software center.

If you can download it in a .deb package you just need to double click on it to install it with software center.

It looks like it is available on there site in source code format though.

Comment: Is there a way to encourage Ununtu to update it?

Comment: No, you will have to install from third party for the latest, mainly the only updates are security or updates to fix issues with applications that do not work correctly.

Comment: "there" being who? and what would have to be done to have it work like a Ubuntu distro?

Comment: I researched and there is not a Pari GP 2.7.1 in .deb or ppa form, so you will have to install it from the link you posted if you want the new version. Please accept the answer so everyone will benefit, I realize you may not like the answer but it is correct.